How should I be handling If-Modified-Since response headers in M?
I'm accessing a web API using Power Query M (Excel) that updates roughly once every hour and provides fairly standard Last-Modified/If-Modified-Since functionality for caching. I have two questions:

the response header contains a Last-Modified timestamp that tells me when the server last refreshed the dataset. How do I access this part of the response header? It seems like Power Query does not expose this field?

how should I be gracefully handling the Not Modified response from within the query and from outside? (I use a VBA script to refresh the query.) As per the standard, if the dataset has not been modified since the date passed the API response will only contain a header with status code 304 and there is no document body attached to it.


I can construct the header properly using a response=Web.Contents() call and see that the API responds as expected (if the data has changed since the Last-Modified timestamp provided in the header I get a 200-response code (OK) and document body, if it has not changed I get a 304 (Not Modified) code and no body.)

Regarding the Last-Modified timestamp, I can access the header data with Value.Metadata(response) and see the response code (200 or 304) but nowhere in the header is the Last-Modified timestamp. There is an API response timestamp that I can use in a pinch but the Last-Modified timestamp would be better because it tells me when the dataset was refreshed and it gives me an idea of when to expect the next update. I know the API is working and passing back Last-Modified because I can query it through a browser and see the response.)

Regarding error handling, I currently don't do anything to look at the response code in Power Query M. I refresh the query from a VBA script and if I get a 304 Not Modified response from the API the query fails and kicks out, raising a generic 1004 error in VBA (accessed through Err.Number). 304 Not Modified isn't really an error, it is a valid response to the query I submitted, but I understand how Power Query can't proceed through the rest of my script without any data in the body so this makes some kind of sense. However, 1004 is a generic error and the only way I can verify what happened outside the query is to search the Err.Description text that kicks out to VBA to look for the keywords "(304): Not Modified". Its ugly and I don't know if that error description will change with language settings of the user (the Excel spreadsheet that all of this is contained in is used in different regions.)



Sounds like you may have more flexibility if you perform the API query outside of M, just using VBA?

...or just use VBA to perform a HEAD request on the API before refreshing the API data via Power Query (assuming the Last Modified header was in range)

@TimWilliams Ok, that makes sense. I can do the HEAD request in VBA and only do the Power Query refresh if I get a 200 response. Thanks.
